# Refreshing part of the DOM via jQuery

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to refresh part of the DOM via jQuery?

I'm using drag & drop and when a div is dropped I need to update the dom so that dropped item new position is accessable via the dom.

BTW I'm not looking for any information with regards jQuery to drag and drop

So for example just refresh all elements contained within a specific `<div>`?

Comment: Yes. it is possible to refresh the DOM via JQuery. What is your actual requirement, can you please edit your question and functionally describe the same?

Comment: Please provide more information and clarify what exactly you want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried "on"?

on the "droppable" div (assuming its called" "drop-div")

```
$(document).on('drop','#drop-div',function() { // Drop is an event fired by UI droppable
//do your thang.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need to do is write a unique script on the server that you call when you want to populate this element, and than call:

```
$('#element').load('your_script.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to get the particular element of the page you needed refreshing using something like:

```
var newcontent = $.get(currentPagesURL + "#some-a-tag");
```

then replace its content with something like:

```
$('#some-a-tag').html(newcontent);
```

However my jQuery is somewhat rusty.